# How add item transparency inside RecyclerView when it's out of list border?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation

How make `RecyclerView` item disappear smoothly when it is going out of list border? See image below. All possible solutions highly appreciated!

[image]

**Note:** Solution with `View` above `RecyclerView` which has gradient background (shadow imitation) does not work well because I have **gradient background** on screen and it is difficult to match that "shadow" view background to screen background and it look like that:[image]

So, works like shadow not like disappearance.

**UPDATED:** Got the second screen with following background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#FF14141d"
        android:endColor="#0014141d"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Here is original screen background

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need, but why not use a gradient that goes from fully transparent to opaque black with a height of e.g. 4dp?

Comment: @npace because I have not solid screen background and this solution leads to shadow effect (like on second image and here you can see it better http://screencast.com/t/njDZjBkF3la). It has the same color with screen background on right and left side of list but different color on list center.

Comment: @npace I need flat page effect but smooth item disappearance.

Comment: @DeeV but near the left and right border you get 14141d (or near)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you want to fade edges, you can use:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical" <-- this line
        android:fadingEdgeLength="150dp" <-- this line, the height of fade 
/>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!